# Wrong output, Erro in Loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
n = [1, 2, 3]

def normalize(n):
    p = []
    for i in range(len(n)):
        p.append(i / sum(n))
        return p

print(normalize(n))
```

> After call `normalize(n)`, I expect the output: `[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5]`
>
> But it is given me the wrong output `[0.0]` What should I do?

Comment: The indentation of your `return` statement is wrong. Additionally, you normalize the index i, not the values in your list.

Comment: You return on your first itertation: `return p`. That should be outside the loop.

Comment: In addition to the indentation error, I think you actually want `p.append(n[i] / sum(n))`. You can also do this using a list comprehension: `print([x/sum(n) for x in n])`

Comment: Thank you!!! I did the corrections and get the correct output